# Clipboard working?

Tags: xcode, string, copy, paste

I have a simple project where I have several NSStrings combined into one. Then, that string is copied to the clipboard. Here is the code:

```
#import "CopyToClipViewController.h"

@interface CopyToClipViewController ()

@end

@implementation CopyToClipViewController
@synthesize device;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (self.device) {
        NSString *namevalue;
        NSString *versionvalue;
        NSString *companyvalue;
        namevalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"name"];
        versionvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"version"];
        companyvalue = [self.device valueForKey:@"company"];

        NSString *shareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I have performed %@ minutes of %@ %@",namevalue, versionvalue, companyvalue];

        UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        pasteboard.string = shareString;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

However, after I build and run the project in the simulator, I can't seem to paste the string into any other app. What is the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can paste it only in simulator-open some app with textfield and longpress the textfield. Tap paste

Comment: I already have. Many times. Now it ends up pasting the entire code for the view controller. Any ideas?